# Python - Display string containing entity references as normal text

Tags: python

I have a Python string `"&#039;&#039;Grassmere&#039;&#039;"`
as retrieved from a website.

I would like to have the `&#039;` displayed as the correct ascii symbol (`'`) but for some reason python insists on just printing the ascii code.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208916/decoding-html-entities-with-python.

Comment: @KennyTM: Not quite the same issue; BS handles the entity references itself.

Answer (score 3):

Batteries are included for this one

```
>>> import xmllib
>>> X=xmllib.XMLParser()
>>> X.translate_references("&#039;&#039;Grassmere&#039;&#039;")
"''Grassmere''"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or without additional modules:

```
re.sub("&#(\d+);", lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1))), "&#039;&#039;Grassmere&#039;&#039;")
```