# Python URL Characters

Tags: python, html, html-entities

I really new to Python and coding in general, but I have been making some good strides.

I am able to pull some data off of the web through an API, and the result should be a string.  What I am seeing though, are some instances such as "& amp;"" and " &quot". (I modified the character sets so it would print properly to the screen)

I figure there is a way to clean this string and remove the characters such that it looks like it does on a computer screen.  I tried searching for urldecoding, but admittedly I dont even know if that is the solution.

Any help on how to remove these "extra" characters and produce a readable string will be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks in advance,

Brock

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208916/decoding-html-entities-with-python  The keyword is `HTML entity/ies`.  Many python libraries help you convert or deal with these in various ways.

Comment: Where are you getting these data? Presumably these are part of an HTML or XML file, and in parsing it your parser should automatically unescape it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[xml.sax.saxutils.unescape](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.utils.html)(data[, entities]): Unescape '&amp', '&lt', and '&gt' in a string of data.

You can unescape other strings of data by passing a dictionary as the optional entities parameter. The keys and values must all be strings; each key will be replaced with its corresponding value. '&amp', '&lt', and '&gt' are always unescaped, even if entities is provided.